# Using the word "apart"

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, adjectives, phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

A doctor says  " you have to take this medication 3 times a day"
Does the following questions ok to be asked ? ( Grammatically speaking )

1-How many hours apart are there between each time ?

2- There are three hours apart between each time.

Comment: I don't understand #2. Is it supposed to be a question, or an answer to the first?

Comment: t.i.d.  = three times a day usually means every 8 hours. Assuming your doctor didn't specify, they probably mean you are supposed to take it first thing in the morning, early afternoon and evening, You can always call them and ask, though: "what's the time interval between each dose?".

Comment: @Rattler the first sentence is question  and the second one is just a statement, and they are not related .I am just asking if either sentences is ok to say  describing the situation.

Comment: Well...the reason I asked is because your question says "*Does the following _questions_ ok to be asked ? "

Comment: Your examples are not idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is the [**interval**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interval):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a**: a space of time between events or states

So:

> "Take this medication 3 times a day."
>   "Do you mean at 8-hour *intervals*?

Or:

> "What is the *interval* between doses?"

Note, too, the use of [*dose*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dose) in the second example.

---

I'm not certain if either of the sentences in the question is *technically* ungrammatical (in violation of actual grammar rules), but they are both at least awkward and not how people would typically phrase them.

The main problem is the use of *each time* rather than something like *dose*. Also, pairing *apart* with *between* is redundant.

---

If you don't want to use *interval* (or *dose*), and keep the sentences as close to the original as possible without them sounding quite strange, the following might be used:

> "How many hours apart should I be taking the medicine?"
>   "How many hours should there be between the times I take it?"
>   "Take the medicine every three hours."

---

After a series of comments, it's been brought to my attention that it might be considered unusual to use the word *apart* or *between* with a singular noun, even in context.

In short:

- ✔ How many hours are there between **doses**.
- ？ How many hours are there between **each dose**.

While the singular form has always been colloquial and idiomatic in my own use and experience in Canada, it seems it's unusual in other places. To me, the singular version actually sounds *more* natural—although I have no problem with the plural version, and would probably use it in strictly formal writing.

Although it would be understood, those who aren't used to the singular version could pause upon hearing it.

So, using the singular version seems to be normal in some places, but uncommon, and a little odd, in others.

Comment: Implicit in your examples and perhaps worth making explicit is that "between" should have two things as its object. In other words, "between times" is OK but "between each time" is not, since "each time" is singular.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Actually, I don't agree with that—at least not fully. I don't see anything wrong with, for example, *There was a sticker placed between each shelf*. In that sentence *shelf* is singular, and there's no problem with using *between*. I think you're complaining more about the use of *each time* than anything else. But the problem with it isn't that it's singular, but the use of *each time*, specifically, which is an odd expression to use here (which I've already said). It's not even that it's temporal. I could say *I got hungry between each visit* just as easily.

Comment: @ Jason Bassford  Thanks a lot for this wonderful explanation.        So I can just easily say :                                                                                How many hours are there between each dose ??

Comment: @Mohamedkz Yes, that sentence is fine. You could even shorten it, if you're speaking or writing informally, to just *How many hours between each dose?*

Comment: Yes, we definitely disagree. I don't consider "between each dose" or "between each shelf" correct. My nearest dictionary says "Between is used in speaking of two things, people, etc." but this is in the context of contrasting "between" with "among", so it only weakly supports my opinion. Another weak support is that all of the dictionary's 18 examples of adjectival use of "between" have plural objects.

Comment: @AndreasBlass At least here in Canada, it's a normal way of expressing the concept. While in formal writing I would use the plural or rephrase, the use of the singular is both colloquial and idiomatic it, and only to be avoided in the strictest of contexts. It might have something specific to do with the somewhat grey area in which *each*, although specifying a singular subject, still puts it in the context of a plural number of subjects. Or it might just be the specific phrase itself. I'm not sure. But I do know it sounds perfectly normal to me.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I'm curious: Does it make a difference to you if I say *put an X on the wall **in** between each shelf*? I know that in that sentence I'm talking about at least two shelves; I'm not talking about putting an X on the wall in the middle of a single shelf. It's at least because of the word *each* being present. If I were talking about only one shelf, then I would say to *put an X on the wall in the middle of **the** shelf*, and I wouldn't use *between* at all.

Comment: No, the presence of "in" would make no difference to me. I'd probably say "in between each two shelves".

Comment: @AndreasBlass Interesting. I appreciate this difference in idiomatic usage. I hadn't been aware of it before. I've updated my answer with the information from this discussion. Incidentally, *between each two shelves* sounds bizarre to me. I would first of all say *between every two shelves,* and, secondly, it actually means something different to me than my singular version. When I hear between *each two shelves* I visualize this: shelf, shelf, X, shelf, shelf, X, shelf, shelf, and so on. If I were to use *each* (albeit with this different sense), I would say *between each pair of shelves*.

Comment: I agree that "every" sound better than "each" in this example.